# Variogram fit in R not converging

Tags: r, spatial, kriging, variogram, gis

I have taken a shapefile from Open NYC Data and performed the following method. My end goal is to predict Taxi `trip_duration` at various points across the city of NYC in March at given time segments. I have a source file of Taxi trips that have lon/lat for the pickup and dropoff of each trip. I also have the `trip_duration` for each trip.

First, I take the shapefile from NYC website [here](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Housing-Development/Shapefiles-and-base-map/2k7f-6s2k).

Below are my code procedures to create this model.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gstat)
library(sp) # install.packages("sp")
library(sf) # install.packages("sf")
library(stars) # install.packages("stars")

# load the shapefile from the NYC data file
shape_sf <- read_sf(dsn = "geo_export_bb23e483-f78f-469f-87f2-00a576a7456f.shp")
> shape_sf <- read_sf(dsn = "geo_export_bb23e483-f78f-469f-87f2-00a576a7456f.shp")

# Not sure if these warnings are important or not.
Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
4: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
5: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation


# take my raw data frame (with the individual trip data) and turn it into a shapefile type as well 
# not sure if I need to change the CRS but I chose it to be matching the .shp file I loaded from NYC
nyc_data_sf <- st_as_sf(nyc_train2, coords = c("pickup_longitude", "pickup_latitude"), crs = st_crs(shape_sf))


# join the nyc_trip data to the shapefile where it contains the points in the shapefile.
shape_df <- st_join(shape_sf, nyc_data_sf, join = st_contains)
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_contains assumes that they are planar

# removing missing values of points that were not on shapefile polygons
shape_df_cleaned <- shape_df[!is.na(shape_df$trip_duration),]

# create grid of values to predict for
spat_pred_grid <- expand.grid(lon = seq(min(nyc_train2$pickup_longitude)-1, max(nyc_train2$pickup_longitude) + 1, length = 20),
                              lat = seq(min(nyc_train2$pickup_latitude)-1, max(nyc_train2$pickup_latitude) + 1, length = 20)) 

# make grid a shapefile object as well
grid_sf <- st_as_sf(spat_pred_grid, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = st_crs(shape_sf))
grid_sp <- as_Spatial(grid_sf)

Warning messages:
1: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded datum Unknown based on WGS84 ellipsoid in CRS definition
2: In showSRID(SRS_string, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded datum WGS84 in CRS definition

# run variogram. This is where I think I have issues
trip_duration_vgm <- variogram(trip_duration~1, shape_df_cleaned)
trip_duration_fit <- fit.variogram(trip_duration_vgm, model = vgm(1, "Lin", 900, 1))

Warning message:
In fit.variogram(trip_duration_vgm, model = vgm(1, "Lin", 900, 1)) :
  singular model in variogram fit

# the plot seems sensible
plot(trip_duration_vgm, trip_duration_fit)

# finally try to Krige
trip_duration_kriged <- krige(trip_duration ~ 1, shape_df_cleaned, grid_sp, model = trip_duration_fit)

# Error here
> trip_duration_kriged <- krige(trip_duration ~ 1, shape_df_cleaned, grid_sp, model = trip_duration_fit)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘coordinates’ for signature ‘"Spatial"’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded datum Unknown based on WGS84 ellipsoid in CRS definition
2: In showSRID(SRS_string, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded datum WGS84 in CRS definition
3: In proj4string(d$data) :
  CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
4: In proj4string(newdata) :
  CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
```

[image]

So I obviously have some warnings and issues here but I am trying to understand why/what is going on. I am new to spatial-temporal analysis and have had a difficult time learning from my Professor. So I am just trying to learn from examples online and apply it to a real data set.

UPDATE:

I changed my code slightly to get a fit using the `sp` package instead of `sf`. The result of my fit is below:

```
nyc_sf <- readOGR("geo_export_67813205-f2d6-435e-aa6e-3f7b691f154f.shp")
trip_data <- nyc_train2 # 5000 Taxi trips for March

# create grid for prediction
spat_pred_grid <- expand.grid(lon = seq(min(trip_data$pickup_longitude)-1, max(trip_data$pickup_longitude) + 1, length = 20),
                              lat = seq(min(trip_data$pickup_latitude)-1, max(trip_data$pickup_latitude) + 1, length = 20)) 
# give coordinates and make it a SpatialPoints object
coordinates(spat_pred_grid) <- ~lon + lat
gridded(spat_pred_grid) <-  TRUE
proj4string(spat_pred_grid) <- proj4string(nyc_sf)

trip_data_spatial <- trip_data
# make it a spatial object
coordinates(trip_data_spatial) <- c("pickup_longitude", "pickup_latitude")
proj4string(trip_data_spatial) <- proj4string(nyc_sf)

# join NYC shapefile to the trip data
trip_data_merged <- sp::over(trip_data_spatial, nyc_sf)

# complete the join
trip_data_spatial@data <- cbind(trip_data_spatial@data, trip_data_merged)

# make the model
trip_duration_vgm <- variogram(log(trip_duration)~1, data = trip_data_spatial)
trip_duration_fit <- fit.variogram(trip_duration_vgm, model = vgm(1,"Gau",100,1))
plot(trip_duration_vgm, trip_duration_fit)
```

[image]

Comment: Automatic methods of variogram fitting are not guaranteed and *always* should be supplemented with careful, knowledgeable analysis.  Fortunately that's easy in this case: assuming the range of distances shown is characteristic and that all calculations have been performed in a meaningful way (one should question your distance metric), you have no evidence of spatial correlation. That's valuable information, because it indicates you don't need to adopt complex models of spatial correlation and you can focus on other kinds of models.

Comment: @whuber Great. I found a way to make the fit converge. I transformed the trip_duration variable to log(trip_duration) and used a Gaussian ```vgm```. However the estimate doesn't look great. I'll update my post with the picture of the fit. Also I performed the "kriging part" and it is working but it is running very slowly.

Comment: Sure, it'll work: but it's not worth the effort.

Comment: @whuber I see. Since there is no spatial correlation kriging won't be useful here since there is no distance relationship. How should I move to actually model the trip duration for my grid?

Comment: Trip data are messy so I would expect to work hard.  I would start by exploring the data to look for relationships between the start location, the terminus, and the time of day.  I would attempt to measure distance as an estimated travel time based on the best routes available at those times and the average traffic speeds throughout the city street segments at those times.  It ought to be possible to estimate those averages with a careful analysis of all trip data.  You will need a fully detailed map of the city streets including information about one-way restrictions.